# How to active caching on Express - Node.js?

Tags: caching, node.js, express

how can i active the caching on Express to provide the pages quickly?

Thank you

Answer (score 14):

You should only enable caching in production:

```
app.configure('production', function(){
  var oneYear = 31557600000;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Furthermore you are probably better of using CDN or Nginx to host static files. A lot of CDN's aren't that expensive and I even found this free CDN at http://www.coralcdn.org/ thanks to stackoverflow.com. According to [this blog post Nginx even has memcached](http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/) to make your site extremely fast

Comment: I think you meant "aren't that expensive" or "are relatively cheap". :)