# How to cache .jpg in memory for Express middleware?

Tags: node.js

I have this Express middleware to deliver thumbnails (.jpeg) on demand:

```
    app.get('/thumb/:index', function(req, res){
        var index = req.params.index

        if (!index) return res.status(404).send()

        var jpeg = PATH.join('./thumbs/', index, '.jpg')
        res.status(200).sendFile(jpeg)
    })
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573315/how-to-active-caching-on-express-node-js) answer shows how to do it when using `.static` but I'm not sure how to use it on a `app.get` middleware.

The goal is to cache all jpeg thumbnails on memory to speed up response and avoid physical disk acccess all the time.

Comment: This will help you http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way that works and that I could come up with in less than 10 minutes.

The infamous use of a global variable is applicable here. The const `cacheMap` is a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that will cache the binary content in memory using the `index` const as its key.

It is probably not the best implementation of all, but it is better than many possible solutions and it works.

Don't forget to remove/comment the console.log calls that are there just for your to see that the follow-up requests don't print the "reading file ..." string

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = require('express')()
const cacheMap = new Map()

app.get('/thumb/:index', async function (req, res) {
  const { index } = req.params

  if (!index) return res.status(404).send()

  const jpeg = path.join(__dirname, 'thumbs', `${index}.jpg`)
  if (!cacheMap.has(index)) {
    console.log('reading file', jpeg)
    cacheMap.set(index, await fs.promises.readFile(jpeg))
  }
  console.log({ index })

  return res
    .header('content-type', 'image/jpeg')
    .status(200)
    .send(cacheMap.get(index))
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is plain and simple. No 3rd party packages needed and I can handle the `cacheMap` myself.